# Why Oracle connection to HANA works much faster with bind variables

Tags: oracle, variables, bind, gateway, hana

we have a problem with connection from Oracle to SAP HANA (by Oracle Gateway). SQLs works much faster when using bind variables in execute immediate than while executing standard SQLs.

F.e.:

```
select count (1) from SYNONYM_TO_HANA_TABLE where field='1234';
```

Elapsed time: 96.808 s

```
    declare
v_test number;
begin
execute immediate 'select count (1) from SYNONYM_TO_HANA_TABLE where field= :a'   into v_test using '1234';
dbms_output.put_line('return: ' || v_test);
end;
/
```

Elapsed time: 0.179 s

Basicly both SQLs returns same result but maybe someone will be able to explain why there is such a difference between execution time. Thanks!

Piotr

Comment: What order was for those queries?
First in plain sql next in execute immediate.

Comment: I've tried both - reconnect and execute with execute immediate, without execute immediate; reconnecte and execute w/o e.i., with e.i.. Always execute immediate works much faster than SQL without bind variables.

Comment: In the code you posted, the execute immediate example never assigns the result to the variable.
Could it be that the execution is simply skipped? If that's not the case, how about tracing the calls and see what gets send to SAP HANA and how long the different steps (prepare, execute, fetch) take?

Comment: You are right about assigment, it was mistake in post. I've edited post and corrected sql with execute immediate. Is there a possibility to trace this without DBA? I don't have sys priviliges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out what  has been done with those queries. 
First step can be to compare execution plans.

```
select /* my_query1 */  count(1) from SYNONYM_TO_HANA_TABLE ;

declare
begin
  execute immediate 'select  /* my_query2 */ count(1) from SYNONYM_TO_HANA_TABLE ';
end;
/

select sql_id,sql_text from v$sql where sql_text like '%my_quere%' ; 


select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('sql_id',0,'ALL'));
```

Comment: I don't have access to that domain :( corpo security policy

Comment: Query without bind variable is getting data to oracle site and with bind variable is executed @HANA site.

Comment: that's not what the execution plan says. Even if the filter condition would not be passed to HANA in one case, it would not explain that time difference, as the result set would still be a single record.

Comment: Lars can you tell something about long execution time based on those queries plans?

Comment: Sorry - didn't see the REMOTE SQL section the first time around. Looks like Oracle doesn't push down the COUNT(*) aggregation and actually fetches the records... And apparently it also doesn't push down literal filters... No idea if/where you can modify this behaviour.